# How to pass functions to change state from one component to another through the Reactjs ContextAPI

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I need to share the state of a component with several others, I believe that one of the simplest ways to perform this function is using React's context api.

The component that contains the state to be manipulated is the Alert, following the code below:

```
import React, { useState, createContext } from 'react';
import { Snackbar } from '@material-ui/core/';
import MuiAlert, { AlertProps } from '@material-ui/lab/Alert';

function Alert(props: AlertProps) {
  return <MuiAlert elevation={6} variant="filled" {...props} />;
}

type PropsAlertContext = {
  alertOpen: boolean;
  setAlertOpen: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>;
};

const DEFAULT_VALUE = {
  alertOpen: false,
  setAlertOpen: () => {},
};

const AlertContext = createContext<PropsAlertContext>(DEFAULT_VALUE);

const AlertContextProvider: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
  const [alertOpen, setAlertOpen] = useState(false);

  const handleAlertClose = (event?: React.SyntheticEvent, reason?: string) => {
    if (reason === 'clickaway') {
      return;
    }
    setAlertOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <AlertContext.Provider
      value={{
        alertOpen,
        setAlertOpen,
      }}
    >
      <Snackbar
        open={alertOpen}
        autoHideDuration={6000}
        onClose={handleAlertClose}
      >
        <Alert onClose={handleAlertClose} severity="error">
          {children}
        </Alert>
      </Snackbar>
    </AlertContext.Provider>
  );
};

export { AlertContextProvider };
export default AlertContext;
```

And the code of any other component that can access the context created in Alert:

```
import React, { useContext, useCallback } from 'react';

import AlertContext from '../../hooks/Alert';

const OtherComponent: React.FC = () => {
  const { alertOpen, setAlertOpen } = useContext(AlertContext);

  const alert = useCallback(() => {
    setAlertOpen(true);
    console.log(alertOpen);
    // Here return false..
  }, [alertOpen, setAlertOpen]);
  
  return (
    <div>
        <button onClick={alert} type="button">
            alert
        </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default OtherComponent;
```

What happens is the following: I can access alertOpen content through "otherComponent", however, I can't change the state using setAlertOpen.